# Whitelabel on existing Angular 4/5/6/7 project

Tags: angular, angular7, white-labelling

I have an Angular 7 application and I need to create a white label project based on the that. In the white label I need to alter some of the components css and also add new routes / new components. What is the recommended way to approach this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Angular Command Line Interface allows you to generate boiler plate projects, Components, Services and much more. Instructions on how to install and use it can be found at [Angular CLI](https://cli.angular.io/)

There are many, many advantages to using Angular's CLI. I do not recommend skipping learning it, even if things seem a lot easier to just go around it for now.